# Get dictionary from NSMutableArray of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get a `NSMutableDictionary` from a `NSMutableArray`.

I set my array this way:

```
let test : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    test.setValue("Monday", forKey: "day")
    test.setValue("7PM - 8PM", forKey: "hour")

    self.availabilityArray.add(test)

    let test1 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    test1.setValue("Saturday", forKey: "day")
    test1.setValue("8PM - 10PM", forKey: "hour")
    self.availabilityArray.add(test1)

    let test2 : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    test2.setValue("Sunday", forKey: "day")
    test2.setValue("2PM - 8PM", forKey: "hour")
    self.availabilityArray.add(test2)
```

And in another method I try to get the "day" and "hour" value to set them in a `UILabel`.

I've tried to do this :

```
let dico = self.availabilityArray[i] //i being the index of a loop, not important here
self.dayNameLabel.text = (dico as AnyObject).object(forKey:"day") // This line does not work, I want to do something like that.
```

So how can I get the content of my `NSMutableArray` for a precise index as a `NSDictionary` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you do `dico as AnyObject`, when you know it's a `NSMutableDictionary`? Why not then `self.dayNameLabel.text = (dico as NSMutableDictionary).object(forKey:"day")`?

Comment: And why don't you use Swift's Dictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Thanks @Larme, it works now. I did not quite understood how it works until now :)

Comment: @Gargantua I don't speak Swift, but Objective-C. But I guess that XCode what giving an error/warning? Something with subscript or something like that? It's because, you tell the compiler, `dico` is a `AnyObject` (that's what does the `as AnyObject`), but then it replies why should it have a method `object(forKey:)`.

Comment: @Gargantua best practice on stackoverflow is to set an answer as best answer, so people with your problem won't struggle to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Larme I found the solution, I juste replace

```
self.dayNameLabel.text = (dico as AnyObject).object(forKey:"day")
```

With

```
self.dayNameLabel.text = (dico as! NSMutableDictionary).object(forKey:"day") as! String?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use swift 2 (or 3) objects.

declare your array like that :

```
var availabilityArray: [[String: String]] = []
```

then create your dictionaries :

```
var test: [String: String] = [:]
test["day"] = "Monday"
test["hour"] = "7PM - 8PM"
var test1: [String: String] = [:]
test1["day"] = "Saturday"
test1["hour"] = "8PM - 10PM"
var test2: [String: String] = [:]
test2["day"] = "Sunday"
test2["hour"] = "2PM - 8PM"
```

add them to the array :

```
self.availabilityArray.append(test)
self.availabilityArray.append(test1)
self.availabilityArray.append(test2)
```

and finally access the object :

```
let dico = self.availabilityArray[0]
self.dayNameLabel.text = dico["day"]
```

dico["day"] is optional, so use `dico["day"]!` or use a real unwrap with `if let`